# plot stock indicators in python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

i have data from yfinance and stock indicators from pandas_ta which i want to create plots from which can help me decide if i should buy a stock. my problem is i cant visualize squeeze_pro in good way.

the column SQZPRO_20_2.0_20_2_1.5_1' is a numeric value that gives me the blue line
the column SQZPRO_NO is either 1 or 0. 1 means bear market.
the column SQZPRO_OFF is either 1 or 0. 1 means bull market

You can see in the picture that I made a red circle with green bars inside.

the goal:

1. The bars/dots should be easy to see.
2. if SQZPRO_20_2.0_20_2_1.5_1 is positive it must be green and if negativ it mus be red
3. the ultimate goal is to make a replicat of the second picture of the squezze_pro visualization

```
import yfinance
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import plotly.subplots as sp
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

ticker = yfinance.Ticker("GOOGL")
df = ticker.history(period="7d", interval="1h")
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["Date","Open", "High","Low", "Close", "Volume"])

rsi = df.ta.rsi()
macd = df.ta.macd()
squeeze_pro = df.ta.squeeze_pro()
df_samlet = pd.concat([df,rsi,macd,squeeze_pro],axis =1)

# Create subplots in a separate plane with different row heights
fig = sp.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True,
                       subplot_titles=[f'{ticker} Stock Prices', 'Technical Indicators'],
                       vertical_spacing=0.1,
                       row_heights=[0.7, 0.15, 0.15])

# Add Stock Prices subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df_samlet.index,
                open=df_samlet['Open'],
                high=df_samlet['High'],
                low=df_samlet['Low'],
                close=df_samlet['Close'],
                name='Stock Prices'), row=1, col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df_samlet.index,
    y=df_samlet['SQZPRO_20_2.0_20_2_1.5_1'],
    mode= "lines",
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    name='squeeze'
), row=2, col=1)


# Add RSI subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_samlet.index, y=df_samlet['RSI_14'],
                mode='lines',
                name='RSI'), row=3, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_samlet.index, y=df_samlet['SQZPRO_NO'],
                marker_color='red', 
                name='Bear'), row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_samlet.index, y=df_samlet['SQZPRO_OFF'],
                marker_color='green',
                name='Bull'), row=2, col=1)

# Update layout to set figure size
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
                  template='plotly_dark',
                  title_text=f'{ticker} Stock Analysis',
                  xaxis=dict(type='category'),  # Set x-axis type to category which removes the sat and sun gap
                  xaxis_title_text='Date',
                  yaxis_title_text='Price',
                  yaxis2_title_text='squeeze',  # Add y-axis title for ATR subplot
                  yaxis3_title_text='RSI',  # Add y-axis title for RSI subplot
                  height=800,  # Set the height of the figure
                  width=1200)  # Set the width of the figure


# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have not asked anything. Just stated some goals and posted some code. There's no question and therefore no possibility to get answers